# Does ExactTarget require to have Automation Studio enabled for doing a Data Extract Soap API (java)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have implemented a java program which our customers are using to pull data from their ExactTarget accounts. I am using ExactTarget Soap Api with Axis 2.0. The data is pulled by doing a Data Extract Api request. 
One of the clients lately has complained that he has not been able to pull ExactTarget data by using our application because according to ET support he has not enabled Automation Studio.
I took a look at Automation Studio and looks like a new  tool to schedule and automate different activities (Data extract including). 
However, I do not use Automation Studio libraries at all in my code, because I schedule and automate the Data Extract request with totally another solution implemented by the company I work for.

So, eventhough I am not using the Automation Studio at all, is it true that the client needs to have it activated just for the sake that he is doing a Data Extract Api request?
Is there any new policy from Exact Target on what features do you need to have activated in your account to be able to do a Data Extract request?

Thanks in advance,
Erisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be the case.  Data Extract Activities should not require Automation Studio.  You can run it using the SOAP definition found [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextractactivity/).